# Xero Oauth Api: Undefined index oauth_session_handle

Tags: php, xero-api

While integrating xero auth api after first authentication getting Undefined index oauth_session_handle error.
Not receiving the oauth_session_handle paramater in response.

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck with this issue for more than a hour, hope someone find it useful.

oauth_session_handle only exist in Partner application since it only used to renew token which is not supported by Public application.

So, if you are using public application just comment out its usage & you are good to go.